# MPEG-4 decoder gstreamer

Tags: 20.04

I got this error in my GStreamer

Missing decoder: MPEG-4 Video (Simple Profile) (video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, systemstream=(boolean)false, profile=(string)simple, level=(string)1, codec_data=(buffer)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d88002d28045a1463000001b24c61766335382e3133342e313030, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)5/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, parsed=(boolean)true)

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libgstreamer-plugins-bad` and `libgstreamer-plugins-ugly` should solve the problem